# The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: gac, assembly-references, packaging

I have a weird problem I just can't place.

I have a SP 2010 project which contains two sub-projects of type class library (`FirstLib` and `SecondLib`).

The project build fine, no errors whatsoever, but once I deploy to the server I get errors in VisualStudio's "Error List" window:

> The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type `X` is in `FirstLib` and is referenced from `SecondLib`. In the package manifest I specified that both be deployed to GAC and I can see they are there, but I still see that message, and I get it for every type in `FirstLib` that is used by `SecondLib`.

What's even weirder is that in the "Output" window I see this.

> ========== Build: 3 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

What could be the cause for this?

What should I check further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get this exact problem myself. I can't work it out either, but I have noticed that it will only occur when I have certain source code files open and active in Visual Studio (in your case it would be a code file from the SecondLib project), and it would only occur when trying to do a package or deploy action.

If you close the source files from SecondLib before doing a deploy the errors should go away.

Comment: I can reproduce your behavior. If I close all source files I get no error whatsoever. Is this a bug in VS2010? What could be the cause?

Comment: Must be something like that. I mean, all projects actually compile sucessfully, and everything works ok, it's just that VS tell you something is wrong at the end.

Comment: Have the same problem, nothing of these answers here works for me. I am using VS 2012. The question is 2 years old and nobody can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. (Re-)Built successful but deployment to SharePoint and manually packaging (Visual Studio -> Pubish) failed. I solved the problem by switching `"Copy-Local"` to `false` in every project (about 15 Class Library projects and three SharePoint Projects).

I think the problem is the linking between each project so Visual Studio can not resolve the dependencies in the right way.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've added other projects to main package. See http://www.sharemuch.com/2010/03/17/deploying-referenced-assemblies-with-your-vs2010-sharepoint-2010-wsp-solution/

Also you can open in Windows Exploerer - C:\Windows\Assembly and make sure your referenced dlls are deployed to GAC.

Comment: I'm already doing this. Assemblies are added to the package, I see them in the .wsp file and they are also deployed to GAC. The weird error still occurs.

Comment: did you add a reference to both projects to your main project in VS?

Comment: Yes, the main project references the libs.